# How to use Ceiling function with over clause or other option to have ceil value

Tags: sql-server

How can I use ceiling function with over clause. I have to print ceil value of avg of one column that uses over clause

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ceiling` on any numeric expression, just note that in this case the `over` clause is part of the expression:

```
CEILING(AVG(some_column) OVER (PARTITION BY some_other_column))
```

Comment: Is there any other option without using partition by

Comment: @Radhikasinghal this was just an example. You can have whatever you need in the `over` clause, it won't affect the way you call `ceiling` on it